# Updating fields doctrine symfony mysql

Tags: symfony

Here is the code on the console.

```
ubuntu1256:~/httpdocs/site$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE campaign CHANGE adresse_email_business_partner  adresse_email_business_partner   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
ubuntu1256:~/httpdocs/site$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "1" queries were executed
```

I continue to force but it doesn't updates correctly. Any ideas? I wanted to add a field in a class.

Comment: Does your user defined in the `parameters.yml` file has all rights on the database ?

Comment: By the way, I can't see any error. What do you mean by "doesn't updates correctly" ? What are you expecting ? Make your question more specific please.

Comment: the problem is I can't modify the column name of the table, but the message says it's successfully donne. Thanks

Comment: Actually `ALTER TABLE campaign CHANGE adresse_email_business_partner  adresse_email_business_partner   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL` does not change the field name. You should provide the code of your entity in your question.